# Need inputs to delete bulk data faster

Tags: performance, oracle11g, sql-delete, bulk

Database: Oracle 11g

Scenario:

- TABLE_A has around 50 million records
- TABLE_A has COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E

  - COLUMN_A is the primary key of TABLE_A

We need to delete around 30 million records from TABLE_A

So, we created another Table TABLE_B
TABLE_B has COLUMN_A with all the GUIDs qualifying for delete from TABLE_A based on TABLE_A.COLUMN_A
TABLE_B has another column QUALIFIER which is populated with sequence starting from 1 to max count of records, say 30 million
TABLE_B is also range based partitioned based on the QUALIFIER column. Each range is split in 3 million records

Which approach among the below would be most efficient way of deleting the records given the above scenario. We are planning to perform this task over a weekend with minimal downtime and also to avoid any segment space issues due to bulk delete:

- Approach-I: Use the direct delete statement without any conditions as follows
  Delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B)

  Also, can we use parallel hints to improve the performance:

  ```
   Delete /*+ parallel first_rows*/ from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select /*+ parallel first_rows*/ COLUMN_A from TABLE_B);
  ```
- Approach-II: Delete the records from TABLE_A by splitting the data based on QUALIFIER column count range to avoid segment space issues if any. And also the records can be deleted in iterations.

  ```
  Delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B where QUALIFIER between 1 and 300000);
  Delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B where QUALIFIER between 300001 and 600000);
  Delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B where QUALIFIER between 600001 and 900000);
  ```

  etc, until

  ```
  Delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B where QUALIFIER between 2700001 and 3000000);
  ```

  Also, can we use parallel hints in the above delete statements to improve the performance
- Approach-III: Delete the records from TABLE_A by splitting the data based on the partitions on the TABLE_B

  ```
   delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B PARTITION (TABLE_B_PARTITION_1));
   delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B PARTITION (TABLE_B_PARTITION_2));
   delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B PARTITION (TABLE_B_PARTITION_3));
  ```

  etc, until

  ```
   delete from TABLE_A where COLUMN_A in (select COLUMN_A from TABLE_B PARTITION (TABLE_B_PARTITION_10));
  ```

  Also, can we use parallel hints in the above delete statements to improve the performance

Is there any other better approach to follow for the above mentioned scenario?

Comment: If you're deleting more rows than you're keeping, I'd simply create a copy of the table with the rows you wish to keep, drop the old table and rename the new table back to the old table's name. You could consider partitioning the new table, which might make deleting data easier in the future, e.g. if you partition on a date column and you want to delete rows where that date is older than, e.g. a year, you can drop partitions that contain rows older than a year.

Comment: Hi Boneist, thank you for the inputs.

Comment: Hi Boneist, thank you so much for the inputs. Creating another table with the required records is not an option we are looking for, the reason being the count of retained records is much more than the records qualifying for delete. Also, the size of the table is in TBs due to some clob data in one of the columns due to which another copy of the same table would consume huge amout of space. sorry to mentioning the record count of table_A as 50 million records, that was just an example. Could you please help review which would be best appraoch among the ones mentioned above.

Comment: The only way you can tell which is the best option for you and your data is to test them and pick the one which works best according to your requirements